# live-server Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8080. even changing the ports not working?

Tags: javascript, npm, server

I just want to run live-server
but every time I run it, it says listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8080 error

even I tried it with different ports but error is not already gone.

live-server   ====> Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8080 error
live-server --port=8090 ====> Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8090 error
live-server --port=7070 =====> Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:7070 error[image]

the solution to this error is just change the port. but when I changed the port the error is already there. so it's a new question.